# ASP.NET MVC: does AntiForgeryToken work in mono?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mono, xsp

I'm trying to use the `Html.AntiForgeryToken` in ASP.NET MVC under Mono (XSP) and it does not work. It throws the following exception. Any ideas?

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: inputString
  at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize (System.String inputString) [0x00006] in /home/danipen/Downloads/mono-2.8/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/ObjectStateFormatter.cs:131 
  at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load () [0x00007] in /home/danipen/Downloads/mono-2.8/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.cs:57 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium () [0x0000f] in /home/danipen/Downloads/mono-2.8/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/Page.cs:1763 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageViewState () [0x00000] in /home/danipen/Downloads/mono-2.8/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/Page.cs:1769 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.RestorePageState () [0x00051] in /home/danipen/Downloads/mono-2.8/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/Page.cs:1454 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.InternalProcessRequest () [0x001b9] in /home/danipen/Downloads/mono-2.8/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/Page.cs:1433 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x0005b] in /home/danipen/Downloads/mono-2.8/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/Page.cs:1261
```

Do you know any other way to implement this?

Thanks in advanced.

**Edit**: This is my view code (it's a partial view). If I remove the line `<%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>` all works fine, in other case it thows the exception described above.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Codice.Web.Client.Comment>" %>

<div class="comment" style="background-color: #009ACF">
 <div class="comment-meta">
  <p class="comment-author">
   <span class="avatarimage">
    <%= Html.AvatarFor(Model.CommentInfo.Owner) %>
   </span>
   <strong class="comment-author">
     <%= Html.Encode(Model.GetAuthorString()) %>
   </strong>
   says:
  </p>
  <p class="comment-date">
   <%= Html.TimeAgo(Model.CommentInfo.LocalTimeStamp) %>
  </p>
 </div>

 <div class="comment-body">
  <div class="formatted-content">
   <%= Html.Encode(Model.CommentInfo.Comment) %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-content">
   <% using(Html.BeginForm(
                   "EditComment",
                   "Comments",
                   new
                   {
        repository = Model.Repository,
        commentId = Model.CommentInfo.Id
       },
                   FormMethod.Post,
                   null))
       { %>
           <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
        <%= Html.TextBox("newComment", Model.CommentInfo.Comment) %>

        <div class="form-actions">
         <a class"edit-cancel minibutton" href="#">
          <span>Cancel</span>
         </a>
         <button class="minibutton" type="submit">
          <span>Update comment</span>
         </button>
        </div>
        <%
       }
   %>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the same code works under MS .NET?

Comment: I'm using AntiForgeryToken in MVC webapp hosted on apache with mod_mono and it works without problems. Can you past your view and controller code?

Comment: @Tomi: Sure, I'm updating the post to paste the view code. The controller is not a problem, only fails compiling the view on runtime.

Comment: @Michael, No I did not test it under .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute set on you controller action which is serving the POST verb?

**Edit:** Possible solution for this issue is probably using the newest mono from master branch, because this problem can be replicated on older versions of mono (for example tarball from April 22 is causing the same exception).

**Edit 2:** What is probably really needed to get this working is setting up valid [machineKey element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx) in web.config file. Keys can be generated for example with [this](https://github.com/spokino/ASP.NET-Machine-Key-Generator) utility.

Comment: @Tomi: Yes, the problem is in the partial view. Actually if I remove the `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` from the view, the controller works fine throwing an Exception (Required antiforguery token was not found...).

Comment: Hmm, this looks odd. Can you past the generated html source to see if the anti forgery token is present in the hidden field under your form?

Comment: @Tommy: Any idea? What version of Mono are you trying?

Comment: @Daniel: I have mono 2.9 (from github master downloaded on November 20). XSP and mod_mono are also from the same date master branch. Can you try to run your webapp through apache with mod_mono?

Comment: Did you get this working in XSP? I have just come up against this error message and would like to know how this was resolved? For reference I am using OpenSUSE 11.3, Mono 2.8.1, ASP.NET 4, ASP.NET MVC 2.0 and using Mono Develop 2.4.2